# .NET: How to pass command-line parameters with a temp file name

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-2.0

This is .NET 2.0 WinForms. I have some code like so

```
string str = Path.GetTempFileName();
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.Arguments = str
psi.FileName = <some executable >
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.Start();
```

Now on the "started" process I get the temp file name by saying `args[0]`. On Win XP this is causing an issue as the temp file is in `C:\Documents and Settings\...`.
The space is causing an issue, thus `args[0]` is `C:\Documents`.

How can I fix this? Do I just have to place `str` in quotes? Or can I get the whitespace to be ignored somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use quotes.

Comment: More than that, you should always use quotes in this scenario because you never know what paths you might run into. The temporary file location, like many other paths, can be customized to be anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can either wrap the path in double quotes or you can convert the path into its short (8.3) representation using the native [GetShortPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364989(v=VS.85).aspx) function.